# The route is not directing to the Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing a password reset in Laravel.

I have the following three `routes`

```
Route::get('passwords/reset/{token?}','Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm') ;

Route::post('passwords/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');

Route::post('passwords/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

When I visit `password/reset`, it shows me the following `form` correctly

```
<form action="{{ url('passwords/email') }}" method = 'post'>

<input type="email" name = 'email' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Your Email Here" style = 'text-align:center'>
  <button type='submit'>Send Link to Email to Reset Password</button>

</form>
```

But when I click on **button** `Send Link to Email to Reset Password`, the `URL` in the address bar does not goes for `password/emails` as it should go there according to the `action` specified in the form, where I want to `sendResetLinkEmail` to the `email`.

However, the `URL` remains the same as it is earlier.

This is what I have in `ForgotPasswordController`

```
 public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email', 'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha']);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    if ($response === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
        return back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    // If an error was returned by the password broker, we will get this message
    // translated so we can notify a user of the problem. We'll redirect back
    // to where the users came from so they can attempt this process again.
    return back()->withErrors(
        ['email' => trans($response)]
    );
}
```

I want to `sendResetLinkEmail` to the `email` but that route is not event targeting when I click that `button`, why is this so?

Please help thanks!

Comment: You have a required validation on the `g-recaptcha-response` field which is not present in the form. Are you sure that the third route is a `post`?

Comment: Okay, let me remove that `captcha` stuff

Comment: @dparoli why did you mention that is the third `route` is post ? please share your thoughts

Comment: I removed g-recaptcha-response and it worked ! Thank You @dparoli

Comment: You mentioned that you visited `'passwords/reset'` but that is a `post` route not a `get` route, usually `'passwords/reset'` is a `get` route. But, anyway, glad to be of help.

Comment: `Route::get('password/reset/{token?}')` is the one I visit, you can see the `?` after `/token`, meaning that the `token` is optional for that , which means I can have two routes, one `with` token the other is `without` token @dparoli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a required validation on the `g-recaptcha-response` field which is *not present* in the form.

The `validation` **fails** and you are redirected to the form.

Please try to remove the `g-recaptcha-response` from the validation *rules*.

Answer (score 0):

Try action function

```
<form action="{{action(' Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset  ') }}" method = 'post'>

<input type="email" name = 'email' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Your Email Here" style = 'text-align:center'>
  <button type='submit'>Send Link to Email to Reset Password</button>

</form>
```